# Using Namespaces and autoloader in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader, php-7.4

I'm kinda confused on how Namespaces work with Autoload. I'm currently trying to learn PHP 7.4 and I came to the point where I wanted to learn how to use Namespaces and an Autoloader for the classes.

I'm working on Mac OS with MAMP.

This is the error message I am getting:

> Warning: include_once(classes/Person/Person.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/includes/autoloader.inc.php on line 4

My file structure is like this:

```
- classes
  - Person
    - Person.class.php
- includes
   - autoloader.inc.php
- index.php
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    include 'includes/autoloader.inc.php';
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $person = new \classes\Person\Person('Andre', 24, 'blue');
        echo $person->getName();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

autoloader.inc.php:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    include_once str_replace("\\", "/", $className) . '.class.php';
});
```

Person.class.php

```
<?php

namespace classes\Person;

class Person {
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $eyeColor;

    public function __construct($name, $age, $eyeColor) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->eyeColor = $eyeColor;
    }
}
```

I really don't understand why it is not working. I followed a lot of tutorials but nothing worked. Maybe it has something to do with a configuration in PHP?

Comment: your need to prepend the correct path else after all is done the require will be absolute path `include_once '/classes/Person/Person.class.php'`

Comment: tip: use composer

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i tried to prepend the correct path, both `include_once '/classes/Person/Person.class.php'` and `include_once 'localhost:8888/classes/Person/Person.class.php'` didn't work.. i will have a look into composer thanks. maybe this will help.

Comment: Use absolute paths: `include_once dirname(__DIR__)  . '/'. str_replace("\\", "/", $className) . '.class.php';`.